# What does error 101 mean in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans, ios, android

I keep getting an error 101 when I try to link my clash of clans Apple device account to android. What does error 101 mean, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If your account is linked to GameCenter (Apple), it is probably linked to your iOS device and cannot be played on your Android device